# jquery cancel/ reset

Tags: jquery, timer, setinterval

I have a slider with 5 buttons used to navigate though my gallery. I also have a settimeout function

```
setInterval (simulateClick, 10000);
```

What I am trying to to reset the time out so that if a button is clicked the user has to wait the full 10 seconds before simulate click kicks in.

Answer (score 2):

```
var intervalID = setInterval(simulateClick, 10000);

// reset
clearInterval(intervalID);
```

The [DOC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.clearInterval).